# attr not working in chrome, but working in IE

Tags: jquery

Below is my code, its not working in chrome, but working well in IE. Tried all the methods given in the other threads, but no use.

Hence attaching the full code for any further suggestions.

```
    var changeLink = $("<a />").text(res_ButtonEdit).click(function () {
                showPopupForm(q, action);
                return false;
            });

            var deleteLink = $("<a />").text(res_ButtonRemove).click(function () {
                $(function () {

                    if (confirmDeleteActionDialog.css("visibility") == "hidden") {
                        confirmDeleteActionDialog.css("visibility", "visible");
                    }

                    confirmDeleteActionDialog.dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        position: ["center", 150],
                        width: 300,
                        height: 160,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                text: res_ButtonRemove,
                                click: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    deleteAction(q, form, action);
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: res_PopupCancel,
                                click: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
                return false;
            });

            var logLink = $("<a />").text("Log").click(function () {
                actionItemLogDialog.dialog("open");
                displayActionItemLog(action);
            });

            questionContainerContent.append($("<td cid='11' />").append(changeLink).append("<BR />").append(deleteLink).append("<BR />").append(logLink));

            if (!canEditItemRight) {
                changeLink.attr("disabled", true);
            }

            if (!canDeleteItemRight) {
                deleteLink.attr("disabled", true);
            }

            questionContainerContent = null;
        });
```

Please help to provide some suggestions.

Comment: Try `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: You can't disable anchor elements, it is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
$element.prop("disabled", true);
$element.prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: where does it stop executing? What console did you open?

Comment: I use Microsoft visual studio. it does not stop executing, but the link is not disabled in chrome.

Comment: I'm talking about chrome console, don't you?

Comment: sorry, what is chrome console?

Comment: I see you are nesting DOM ready handler inside click handler, this is just wrong to do it, but could be not related to your issue even ready handler is automaticaly unbound once executed.

Comment: Next, provide a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue otherwise it is impossible to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bind` to disable it.

```
$('.your-link').bind('click', false);
And to unbind / re-enable:

$('.your-link').unbind('click', false);
```

Comment: bind is not showing in IntelliScence, but it did not work as well.